# Accessing route path in event listener

Tags: php, symfony

**ROUTE:**

```
user_lock:
    path:     /user/lock/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteMainBundle:Frontend\Default:userLock }
    methods:  [GET]
```

As you know, router above will create a URL like `htt://mysite.com/app_dev.php/user/lock/66` so I need to get only `/user/lock/66` part of it in event listener below. How can I do it?

I tried `$request->getBaseUrl()` and `$request->getBasePath()` didn't give me what I wanted.

**YAML**

```
services:
    kernel.listener.kernel_controller:
        class: Site\MainBundle\EventListener\Controller\KernelController
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

**CLASS**

```
<?php

namespace Site\MainBundle\EventListener\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

class KernelController
{
    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        $this->writeLog('ROUTE', $request->attributes->get('_route'));
        $this->writeLog('CONTROLLER', $request->attributes->get('_controller'));
        $this->writeLog('ROUTE PARAMETERS', $request->attributes->get('_route_params'));

        $this->writeLog('ROUTE PATH', ??????????????????????????????);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you are looking for

```
$request->server->get('PATH_INFO');
```

Comment: That's the one. Thanks. +1

Comment: Another option: `$event->getRequest()->getQueryString()`